# What is a source of Proj projections definitions?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

I'm trying to create my own implementation of most popular projections (for reasons unrelated with GIS). But I want my implementation to be as compatible with Proj as possible (because it is an unofficial standard for geographical projections).

I've read somewhere (I can't find that source anymore) that Proj uses definitions provided in [Snyder, 1987](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/pp1395). I first implemented Lambert Conformal Conic projection from Snyder and differences between my implementation and Proj are on scale of micrometers (which is more than satisfactory).

But now I'm trying to implement Azimuthal Equidistant projection (ellipsoidal, oblique aspect) and differences between Snyder and Proj are much bigger.

For example for projection specified as `+proj=aeqd +lon_0=30 +lat_0=30 +ellps=WGS84` I get:

```
Projected point: 28.51E, 31.26N
Proj:              x:-141921.025723 y:140622.015288
My implementation: x:-141921.083510 y:140621.956967

Projected point: 32.85E 27.42N
Proj:              x:281885.848749 y:-282529.286543
My implementation: x:281886.321315 y:-282528.815053
```

So the difference is on scale of meters just a few hundred kilometers from the center point. I checked with the provided numerical example in Snyder paper that I correctly implemented the definition.

I also checked the [Proj implementation](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/src/projections/aeqd.cpp) but the code is completely undocumented. Even though there are some similarities between symbols in Snyder and Proj, there is no easy way to understand what Proj actually does. The only information I have found is that aeqd projection in Proj was implemented in 1995 by Gerald Evenden.

Thus I'm wondering what definition of aeqd projection is Proj using and where can I find more information about it.

Comment: Not able to answer the question, but you might like to review the implementation from GeographicLib. See https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/C++/doc/classGeographicLib_1_1AzimuthalEquidistant.html which has links to the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Similarly not an answer - but I would recommend reviewing the formulae in the IOGP Report [373-07-02](https://www.iogp.org/bookstore/product/coordinate-conversions-and-transformation-including-formulas/)

Comment: The Proj mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/proj is active and responsive.

Comment: The answer is now posted. Thanks @BradHards for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks also @JimT, but the comment system won't allow me to mention two people at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research I have found the source of the confusion.

The method for the ellipsoidal oblique aspect I have implemented (described in Snyder, 1987) is called *Micronesia Form* and is listed in the EPSG catalogue as *EPSG:9832 - Modified Azimuthal Equidistant*. This projection is actually not implemented in Proj.

The actual *Azimuthal Equidistant* projection is conceptually very simple. For forward projection you need to find azimuth and distance of projected point from the origin by finding a [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) and then calculate projected coordinates with basic trigonometry.

The non-trivial part of this projection is finding the geodesic on ellipsoid. As far as I found, there is one comprehensive library that allows for geodesic computations ([GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/)) and Proj uses it.

Luckily, GeographicLib is ported to quite a few languages so I was able to implement my own AEQD projection.

But the confusion between *Modified Azimuthal Equidistant* and actual *Azimuthal Equidistant* projection seems to be quite common, as even [PROJ4JS](http://proj4js.org/) implements the `Micronesia Form` without any indication that it does not actually compute AEQD projection.